# How to extract verb phrases from a Stanford NLTK parse tree

Tags: python-3.x, stanford-nlp

I'm using the Stanford parser to generate a parse tree of a sentence such as this one:

```
(ROOT
  (SBARQ
    (WHADVP (WRB how))
    (SQ
      (VBP do)
      (NP (FW i))
      (VP
        (VB add)
        (NP (DT a) (NN link))
        (PP (TO to) (NP (PRP$ my) (NNS links)))))))
```

I want to extract the final verb phrase, so, "add a link to my links", in this case.

I first assumed there was no available method to get out all the verb phrases so I tried using pyparsing to turn the tree into a nested list. I ended up with

`[['ROOT', ['SBARQ', ['WHADVP', ['WRB', 'how']], ['SQ', ['VBP', 'do'], ['NP', ['FW', 'i']], ['VP', ['VB', 'add'], ['NP', ['DT', 'a'], ['NN', 'link']], ['PP', ['TO', 'to'], ['NP', ['PRP$', 'my'], ['NNS', 'links']]]]]]]]`

from which I could try to extract

`['VP', ['VB', 'add'], ['NP', ['DT', 'a'], ['NN', 'link']], ['PP', ['TO', 'to'], ['NP', ['PRP$', 'my'], ['NNS', 'links']]]`

but still, I'm not sure how to search through the nested list to find the VP. I was wondering if there's a method within the Stanford parser code to give back phrases of a certain type.

I'm getting the parse tree like this:

```
import os
from nltk.parse import stanford
os.environ['STANFORD_PARSER'] = '/home/rwitn/stanford-parser'
os.environ['STANFORD_MODELS'] = '/home/rwitn/stanford-parser'

parser = stanford.StanfordParser(model_path="/home/rwitn/stanford-parser/englishPCFG.ser.gz")
sentences = parser.raw_parse_sents(firstQuestionsDF['chat_firstQuestion'])
#print(sentences)

# GUI
counter = 0
for line in sentences:
    for sentence in line:
        firstQuestionsDF.loc[counter]['parseTree'] = str(sentence)
        counter += 1
        #sentence.draw()
        print(sentence)
```

and I'm getting the nested list like this:

```
from pyparsing import *
text = firstQuestionsDF.loc[2]['parseTree']
nestedExample = nestedExpr(opener='(', closer=')').parseString(text)
print(nestedExample.asList())
```

How do you think it is best to go about getting the final verb phrase, or even just a list of verb phrases from this sentence?